# Update mysql rows with formula having different values for each row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Table 1 : parts

- id (primary key)
- code
- title
- quantity

Table 2 : bill_items

- id (primary key)
- bill_id
- parts_id: refers to primary key of table parts
- qty

I would like to update parts table - qty every time I create a row in table bill_items. The qty in parts table is to be decremented by qty of bill_items. There may be N number of updates to table bill_items in one go. Would like to use a single INSERT....ON DUPLICATE or UPDATE statement.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this case better using trigger :

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE
        TRIGGER `bill_items_after_insert` AFTER INSERT 
        ON `bill_items` 
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

            UPDATE parts set quantity = quantity - NEW.qty WHERE id = NEW.parts_id;

        END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I suggest you also make trigger for UPDATE and DELETE also for data consistency.

**UPDATED**

Based on your comment, it is possible to use normal insert and update using transaction for consistency data :

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO bill_items (bill_id, parts_id, qty) VALUES (your_bill_id,your_parts_id,your_qty);
UPDATE parts SET quantity = quantity - your_qty WHERE id = your_parts_id;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Appreciate your support. Is it possible without Triggers?

Comment: @ParndhamanM yes, it is possible, just do it with normal insert and update or make insert and update in a stored procedure https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php

trigger just possible best option I think for you